# What is the best deterministic authenticated encryption algorithm to date?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, deterministic-encryption

We have a main database where certain properties are PII and want to setup a read-only replica so other parts of the business can able to access (e.g. analytics)

We'd like those PII properties to be encrypted, so those with access to the read-only replica of the database would not be able to make sense of any PII. We've decided that we're be OK with runtime en/decrypting those attributes when needed.

We also would like to enable queries that would correlate data, for example: encrypting the same email address would yield the same output.

I shall mention that I know little to nothing when it comes to cryptography… so please bear with me. I've looked around and eventually stumbled upon "nonce-misuse resistant" options that would produce the same output for the same input. But it feels wrong to "abuse" that by deliberatelly misusing nonce to produce the desired output. After some more digging, it seems we're after a *deterministic encryption* algorithm (hence the title – please correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm seeking for advice on what would be, or how to pick, the most appropriate algorithm, given what we're trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably have regulations you need to comply with. You should hire a professional to help you do this. Any answers you get here will just be a starting point.

Comment: I think AES 128 / 256  is a good choice. But with a bad implementation, the whole system can be unsecure

Comment: Indeed, @AmanGrewal… We're just trying to get a bit ahead so we don't go blind to any meetings. Thanks!

Comment: @Titanlord I looked into AES, though it seems I have to pick a mode too. I've looked into GCM, but it requires a nonce and wouldn't produce deterministic outputs. Then I learned about AES-GCM-SIV, which would not catastrophically fail if the same nonce is used more than once – to produce a deterministic output; but as mentioned in the question, it feels like abusing a property of the algorithm that is there to protect us in case of an accidental repeated nonce. Do you know any good modes that'd produce deterministic output? I've read some contradictory opinions out there on which mode to use…

Comment: ECB is the simplest mode. It only uses the key to encrypt. The second mode I know well is CBC. It uses already encrypted data. I think both of them are deterministic.

Comment: @Titanlord: you don't want to be CBC.  My inclination (if performance isn't an issue) would be to use a FPE mode, such as FF1 - to do the authentication part, you'd append a number of 0 bytes before encryption (and check that field for 0's after decryption).  That's slow (and a tad obscure), however it will thoroughly disguise related inputs.  And, you can use the database column as the 'tweak', so that different columns would encrypt differently; for example, it would not be obvious if someone had the same first and last name (I know such a person).